# Converting a string to array of words - Python

Tags: python, arrays, character, substring

I want to create a function in Python, where input will be the String and input it into an array to be returned.

For example:

```
Input: "The dog is red"  
Output: "The", "dog", "is", "red"
```

I believe the algorithm should work, but nothing is returned. From what I can assume, the if statement is not detecting the space ( ").

The code is below:

```
string = input("Input here:")
def token(string):
    start = 0
    i = 0
    token_list = []
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        if " " == string[i:i+1]:
            token_list = token_list + string[start:i+1]
            print string[start:i+1]
            start = i + 1
        i += 1
    return token_list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split the string.

```
result=input.split(" ")
```

or

```
string = raw_input("Input here:")
def token(string):
    start = 0
    i = 0
    token_list = []
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        if " " == string[i:i+1][0]:
            token_list.append(string[start:i+1])
            #print string[start:i+1]
            start = i + 1
        i += 1
    token_list.append(string[start:i+1])
    return token_list

print token(string)
```

Comment: I would, but the assignment is asking me to implement my own tokenizer.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, why did you include the second "token_list.append(string[start:i+1])"?

Comment: @user287474 coz you need to include the last `string` after `space`.You are including `string` before space.So last woule be left out

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function to look like this:

```
string = input("Input here:")
def token(string):
    start, i = 0, 0
    token_list = []
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        if " " == string[i:i+1]:
            token_list.append(string[start:i+1])
            start = i + 1
        i += 1
    token_list.append(string[start:i+1])
    return token_list
    
print token(string)
```

You need to append only up until `i` if you don't want to include the trailing space. The second `append` is necessary because your condition is checking for a space to include the word, but the last word won't have a trailing space, and instead would have an end of line character or null.